# What namespaces are shared among containers in a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes

There are 6 kinds of namespaces in linux: `Network, UTS, Users, Mount, IPC, Pid`. I know that all the containers share the same network namespace with the pause container in a Kubernetes pod. And by default, different containers have different PID namespaces because they have different init process. However, how about other namespaces and why?

Comment: Note: pods can shares processes with Kubernetes 1.12 (Sept. 2018): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52565997/6309

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/):

> Containers in a Pod run on a “logical host”; they use the same network namespace (in other words, the same IP address and port space), and the same IPC namespace.
>
> Containers in a Pod share the same IPC namespace, which means they can also communicate with each other using standard inter-process communications such as SystemV semaphores or POSIX shared memory.
>
> Containers in a Pod are accessible via “localhost”; they use the same network namespace. Also, for containers, the observable host name is a Pod’s name. Because containers share the same IP address and port space, you should use different ports in containers for incoming connections. In other words, applications in a Pod must coordinate their usage of ports.

You can also [enable sharing Process namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/) between containers in a Pod by specifying `v1.PodSpec.shareProcessNamespace: true`.

Answer (score 6):

- ipc, net and uts namespace are shared.
- pid: By
  default its not shared. However the namespace sharing can be enabled in the [pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/).
- mnt: Not shared. Different containers are built from different images. From each container only its own root directory will be visible.
- user: This is not supported by k8s and some form of user namespace sharing could be implemented in the future as mentioned [here](https://kinvolk.io/blog/2020/12/improving-kubernetes-and-container-security-with-user-namespaces/#bringing-user-namespaces-to-kubernetes).

[image]

[img source](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/containers-vs-pods/)