# Is it possible to set the IpcMode for a container with kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ipc

I'm currently using the Docker API to create containers. The [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate) lets me control the IPC mode of them via the `HostConfig.IpcMode` property.

I'm interested in switching away from writing directly to Docker Engine and K8s seems to the the best alternative. My interpretation of the [K8s API Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#-strong-api-overview-strong-) is that the answer to my question is "No", but I'm not confident I'm right.

So, is there a way to do this using K8s' deployment API? I'm new to K8s and overwhelmed by the amount of documentation.

The larger problem I'm trying to solve is to have containers within a pod share memory and condition variables. If there's a better way of doing this in K8s than setting the IpcMode of containers please let me know.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765555/what-namespaces-are-shared-among-containers-in-a-kubernetes-pod/51788814#51788814) might answer your question.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What namespaces are shared among containers in a Kubernetes pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765555/what-namespaces-are-shared-among-containers-in-a-kubernetes-pod)